# Calling Angular apps/functions from Delphi and Delphi functions from Angular

Tags: android, angular, delphi

Is it possible (on Android that is) to call an Angular app from Delphi (Firemonkey) and pass data to it?

And could an Angular app call a Delphi Firemonkey app and pass data to it?

Or how to call Angular functionality from Delphi or Delphi functionality from Angular?

Comment: In my opinion it would be better if you used json or if you plan a server/client look for REST (http verbs + json)

Comment: Yes and no. Is your Delphi app on the device or a web server ? Is your Angular app executed on a ebserver and served by a web browser on the device or embed into the Delphi app ?

Comment: The Delphi app is a apk running on the Android device and the Angular app will also be something running directly on the device.